# Why Links need double touch on the phone to go into the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <a href="https://fufala.ge/ka/product/detail/3762/8496" class="btn btn--round btn--dark">
       <span class="icon icon-eye"></span>
    </a>
```

this is a link with eye icon and it needs double touch on phone to get into it.
I have tried everything like I used javascript and create a function where onclick the link will be redirected but it needs double touch again 
this is css of this button

```
.btn--round {
    border-radius: 999em;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s 0s ease;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .3s 0s ease;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow .3s 0s ease;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .3s 0s ease;
    transition: box-shadow .3s 0s ease;
}
.btn{
display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: About code is very much correct, `href` will open any link on single tap only. Make sure any other Javascript / jQuery coding is not overwritten.

Comment: thanks I am chekcing it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also try a action on hover, sometimes one tap is hover and to taps is click on mobile:

```
 document.getElementById("id").onmouseover= function() {
                window.location.href = "link.html"; 
            };
```

Comment: I found a solution I add ontouchstart event in html with functioon shoit(this) and after that from javascript I grab the link of it and redirecting it with window.location.href